# Delete appsettings.*.json files after publish in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, delete-file

I want to delete all `appsettings.*.json` file after publish in Azure DevOps.
So I added `Delete Files task` as Follows

```yaml
steps:
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete redundant appsetting'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**/appsettings.*.json'
```

[image: Delete Files task]

But it doesn't work at all.
How should I do it?

Comment: Can you use _gitignore_? So you can also prevent pushing secrets to the repository.

Comment: Well, I need them to build at different environments, I want to prevent them to publish

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.
final Task:

```yaml
steps:
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete redundant appsetting'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    Contents: '**/appsettings.*.json'
```

The important thing is putting `DeleteFiles` Task after build Task as follows:

[image: Pipeline]

It worked.